# position relative & absolute height issue for text

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

The problem is when I use more text in the slider; the text is overlapping with button; please see the second image:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul>                
    <li>
        <blockquote></blockquote>
        <p></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <blockquote></blockquote>
        <p></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <blockquote></blockquote>
        <p></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 95;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** I don't want fixed height solution. I am using jQuery Cycle Plugin. Please provide a solution for me.
please see link http://staging.privateproperties.com.au/

Comment: Which solution you want if if there is more text? you can use `overflow:hidden` for that.

Comment: no i need visible all text because it's testimonial..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative 1:
No dynamic height. As you reduced the font-size on long quotes you could add more width to the text container. This way it will drop in less than 4 lines.

Alternative 2:
jQuery cycle has two callback methods before and after. You could use the before method to calculate the height of the text container and add the height of the meatballs. The result is the whole container height. You can modify it before each slider change.

```
$('#some-cycle').cycle({ 
    before:  onBefore, 
    after:   onAfter 
 });

function onBefore() { 
    //Assuming html elements
    var textHeight = $('#textContainer').height(),
        meatballs = $('#meatballs').height(),
        sumHeights = textHeight + meatballs;
    $('#cycle-wrapper-container').height(sumHeights);
}
```

You could animate the height for a better transition.

Comment: Alternative 1: It's not able to use because it's responsive site.when we go to mobile device same problem will come.  Alternative 2: i didn't understand this method.(call back function is used to call from last slide to first slide.how can i use it?) can you please explain how to use in my project.

Comment: Alternative 1, is a solution through CSS. If its responsive it means that the text size in devices should be smaller. This is not happening now. Nevertheless the alternative 2 is a good possibility to make it "elastic". Don't forget to animate the height change between transitions, to avoid the "hard jump" between different heights.

Comment: When you call your `.cycle({ ` you can add the before callback function. This function will execute right before a slide transition. This means each time you change from one slide to another, it will execute a function, in this case called onBefore, that calculates the total height. This way you can modify the outer container height.